# C++, всегда ли возможно избавиться от циклической зависимости между типами?

Tags: c++, циклические-зависимости

Я хочу понять, возможно ли (в принципе) писать код так, чтобы в нем не было циклических зависимостей между типами.

В качестве простого примера рассмотрим такую ситуацию: игровой уровень, в котором есть граната.

Гранате нужна возможность как-то повлиять на уровень. Например, при догорании запала необходимо добавить в уровень взрыв, осколки, кое-какие эффекты, звук. То есть, граната, как реализация оружия, решает, что и как она добавляет. Не уровень. Если это будет решать уровень, тогда для каждой реализации гранаты нужно будет реализовывать алгоритм подрыва внутри уровня. Логически это выглядит неправильно.

Уровень может реализовать интерфейс, через который игровые объекты будут его о чем-то просить:

```
// Battle interface for battle object.
class BIFBO
{
    public:
    virtual void addExplode() = 0;
};

class Battle : public BIFBO;

class BattleObject
{
    private:
    BIFBO &bifbo;
};

class AssaultGrenade : public BattleObject, ...;
```

Это выглядит логично, но от циклической зависимости не избавляет.

И я не могу придумать способ, который бы позволил от нее избавиться. Поэтому я начинаю подозревать, что не все циклические зависимости можно исключить, не нарушив ответственность классов.

Может быть, я неправильно понимаю области ответственности и взаимодействие между типами в описанном случае?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97563/discussion-on-question-by-mgneo-c------).